# How to check Multiple string is not nil and not empty in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check multiple string in if condition if are not nil and not empty.

for now i am doing like

```
  func isSetupDone(token1: String?, token2: String?, token3: String?) -> Bool{

        if token1 == nil || token1!.isEmpty || token2 == nil  || token2!.isEmpty || token3 == nil || token3!.isEmpty {
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

but i guess there should be better way of doing this in swift 5. Please suggest if any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all `String`s to an `Array` and call `allSatisfy` on that array.

```
func isSetupDone(token1: String?, token2: String?, token3: String?) -> Bool {
    let tokens = [token1, token2, token3]
    return tokens.allSatisfy { $0 != nil && $0?.isEmpty == false }
}
```

You can also merge the two conditions into a single one by optional chaining the optional strings, since `$0?.isEmpty == false` will evaluate to `false` in case `$0` is `nil`.

```
func isSetupDone(token1: String?, token2: String?, token3: String?) -> Bool {
    [token1, token2, token3].allSatisfy {$0?.isEmpty == false }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop and optional chcecking

```
func isSetupDone(token1: String?, token2: String?, token3: String?) -> Bool{
    let array = [token1, token2, token3]
    for case let element in array {
        if let element = element , !element.isEmpty {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            return false 
        }
    }
    return true 
}
```

Comment: Empty `if` branches are an anti-pattern. If you only need the `else` branch, negate the condition rather than creating an empty `if` branch.